# Can we make a graph object in py2neo and using other graph object's merge function for merging the graphs?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I want to merge a graph into my graph database using py2neo. My question is can we make a graph object, add all the required nodes and relationships and then using the merge function of object which is an instance of my graphdatabase, merge the created graph in graphdatabase?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific - what do you mean by merge exactly? What have you tried so far? Can you include some code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to merge a subgraph into the main graph database. We can make a subgraph by doing union on all the nodes and relations to be created. And then using graph.merge() we can merge our subgraph into graph. Thank you for considering the question, I found the answer

Comment: and it is a faster way of insertion also